# problem in applying on click listener on button having background image

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an android application in which i have various views.When i apply listener on button having background image the acivity does not pass to other activity.Can anyone tell why is not applying event

Here is my code

```
package com.xib;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {
    private Button Next;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.temp);


     Next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
     Next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Main.this,Main1.class);
            startActivity(intent2);


        }

   });
    }
}
```

and my xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >



<LinearLayout

  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="42px"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="@drawable/navigationbar"
  > 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:text="@string/Back"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/back_btn_blank"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
    android:layout_width="70px"
    android:paddingLeft="7px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<TextView 
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="42px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/PAIN_AREA_HEAD"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
<AbsoluteLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="35px"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="@drawable/gray_bar">

<TextView
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="15px"
    android:paddingTop="7px"
    android:background="@drawable/green_arrow"
    android:layout_width="75px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="248px"
    android:layout_y="1px"
android:text="@string/TEMPERATURE"/>
<TextView
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="17px"
    android:paddingTop="7px"
    android:background="@drawable/green_arrow"
    android:layout_width="75px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="185px"
    android:layout_y="1px"

android:text="@string/COLOR"/> 
<TextView
android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="17px"
    android:paddingTop="7px"
    android:background="@drawable/green_arrow"
    android:layout_width="75px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="123px"
    android:layout_y="1px"
android:text="@string/SHAPE"/>  
<TextView
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="20px"
    android:paddingTop="7px"
    android:background="@drawable/green_arrow"
    android:layout_width="71px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="63px"
    android:layout_y="1px"
android:text="@string/SUD"/>
<TextView
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="13px"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    android:background="@drawable/green_arrow"
    android:layout_width="75px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="0px"
    android:layout_y="1px"
android:text="@string/AREA"/>

  </AbsoluteLayout>
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/background_img">    

<TextView 
    android:textColor="#ff9900"
    android:textSize="15px"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="7px"
    android:layout_width="290px" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Temperature"></TextView>
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="280px"
    android:layout_height="55px"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:background="@drawable/temp_level_bg"
>
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
    android:layout_marginTop="9px"
    android:paddingLeft="28px"
    android:button="@drawable/radio_theme"
android:text="@string/HOT"/>
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
    android:layout_marginTop="9px"
    android:paddingLeft="28px"
    android:button="@drawable/radio_theme"
android:text="@string/COLD"/>
</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:layout_marginTop="180px"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
> 
<Button
    android:id="@+id/prev"

    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="90px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cust_prev_btn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8px"
    android:paddingLeft="26px"
    android:paddingTop="2px"
android:text="@string/PREVIOUS"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="90px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cust_next_btn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="122px"
    android:paddingRight="22px"
    android:paddingTop="2px"
android:text="NEXT"/>   </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: is it crashed ? have you declare Main1 activity in manifest file ?

Comment: Can you tell about your image format and size?

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is deprecated, use FrameLayout or RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put and see `android:clickable="true"` inside your button. Hope it may work. If there any errors, please put the logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `android:enabled="false"` from the Button XML?

I can't actually find this in the API to back up my argument, if anyone has a link. Thanks.